ArcGIS Runtime Package Version Downgrade Exception
I have a C# project (VS 2019, .NET 4.7.2) that uses the ArcGISRuntime Nuget package and has worked great for a few years on both my dev machine (Win10) and the server that runs the process in production (Win Server 2016).  I recently upgraded the Nuget package to version 200.? (the latest) only to find that it is throwing type init exceptions on the server, and that was due to a Windows build incompatability issue. (From what I found out,the 200.? version was incompatible with Win Server 2016.) So I figured downgrading the package version would work. However, when I downgrade (I'm using 100.15), and try to run/debug the project, I am seeing similar errors on my dev machine:
Outer exception: "The type initializer for 'RuntimeCoreNet.GeneratedWrappers.CoreWrapperBase' threw an exception."
Inner exception:"Invalid ArcGISRuntime deployment folder, missing folder D:\VSRepo\SynergiModelBuilderV3\SynergiModelBuilderV3\bin\Debug\arcgisruntime100.15\client32""
The 'arcgisruntime100.15' folder exists, but underneath there is only a 'resources' folder.  I am still seeing the 'RuntimeCoreNet200_3.dll' in the root bin folder (copy local=true). I assume the build is supposed to generate a RuntimeCoreNet100_?.dll.
I manually created the 'client32' folder, reran debug, and it's now looking for the version-specific dll (which I cannot find in the bin folder, just the RuntimeCoreNet200_3 version):
"Invalid ArcGISRuntime deployment folder, missing dll D:\VSRepo\SynergiModelBuilderV3\SynergiModelBuilderV3\bin\Debug\arcgisruntime100.15\client32\RuntimeCoreNet100_15.dll"
I've tried deleting the bin & debug folders and re-building the project, but get the exact same result (it produced the 200.dll, not the 100_15).
I should also mention this is a 32 bit project because of a limitation due to another dll reference (non-ESRI).
I feel like this is a VS build issue, but all my attempts at circumventing has failed.
Any ideas?

Do a full clean and try setting the platform target explicitly to x86. Also upgrade your server. You're way past Microsoft support on 2016. Also I assume this is for terminal apps and not web apps (the latter which is not supported and even violates ToU). Lastly make use you use package references and not package.config since that always creates upgrade problems

Platform was set to x86. This is a console app. I migrated to package reference, deleted bin & obj folder, clean & rebuild, and I now see the 100_15.dll (the 200 dll is still being built too). Now when I run the app, I am getting "Could not load ArcGIS Runtime (RuntimeCoreNet100_15.dll) or one of its dependencies. Ensure "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable" is installed." exception. I re-installed the x86 bit version of the package, but got the same error.

is the PlatformTarget value defined in your csproj file or just the Platform value? I've seen issues with legacy .NET Framework and sdk-style projects not setting this.

I set it in Properties -> Build tab, but when I open the .csproj file in N++ I see this: AnyCPU

I created a fresh project, added the runtime package, and moved some of my code that interacts with the feature service there, and it seems to work (on my dev laptop at least). If this approach works on the server (creating a separate executable), I can run with it.

Not all you need to figure out where the project difference is.

No, because it still won't work on the server: "Could not load ArcGIS Runtime (D:\Synergi Model Builder\bin\RuntimeCoreNet100_15_5.dll) or one of its dependencies. Ensure "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable" is installed." The C++ redistributable is installed. I cannot move from Serer 2016; in the real world we are sometimes forced to play the hand we're dealt. And this is my hand. I've never had this much trouble with a Nuget package in my life.

Try setting Platform to x86. Also set PlatformTarget to x86. (not AnyCPU)
This would really only be an issue if you're using SDK style projects with old .NET Framework because it doesn't correctly set these values. Old-style project types don't have this issue, nor does .NET8.
Wrt hand being dealt: AFAIK it is still not a supported OS by the ArcGIS Runtime.
